# ScikitLearn Extracting Feature Names from FeatureUnion inside a pipeline

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, data-science, sklearn-pandas

I'm using SKlearn's Pipeline model to extract and construct a united feature which is then being sent to a random forest classifier, while some feature extractors can be removed or added later, consider the following structure:

```
model = Pipeline([
                  ('feature_extract',
                     FeatureUnion([
                                   ('feature A', extracorA()),
                                   ('feature B', ExtractorB()),
                                   ('feature C', FeatureUnion([
                                                      ('c1', C1Extractor())
                                                      ('c2', C2Extractor())]))
                                                                               )]),
                   ('random_forest', RandomForestRegressor(...)))])
```

I would like to improve the predictions of the random forest by inspecting the

```
feature_importances_
```

property of the RandomForstRegressor

I managed to get the list using:

```
model._final_estimator.feature_importances_
```

And now I would like to dynamically link between the column number in the feature_importances_ index to the feature name/step in the pipeline.

Is there a preferred way to save/retrieve the feature name inside a feature union? How would you address this issue?

Answer (score -1):

To keep everything in dynamic form, you can use the below function as the transform implementation of a separate class and make the class's object a part of your pipeline. You can even change scoring parameter. I think Grid Search as a part of the pipeline is what you are looking for...

```
def best_config(model, parameters, train_instances, judgements):
    clf = GridSearchCV(model, parameters, cv=5,
                       scoring="accuracy", verbose=5, n_jobs=4)
    clf.fit(train_instances, judgements)
    best_estimator = clf.best_estimator_

    return [str(clf.best_params_), clf.best_score_,
            best_estimator]
```

Comment: Did this help resolve the issue? I'd like to know how Avi implemented this answer or used a different approach. Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't appear to answer the question asked